# How to hide an element via CSS?

Tags: css, wordpress

How can I hide this element using CSS?

```
<nav itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" itemscope="itemscope" class="overlay-navigation visible" role="navigation" aria-label="Elementor Menu"
```

Please help!

Comment: `nav {display: none;}`

Comment: You don't even need CSS for this: `<nav hidden itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" itemscope="itemscope" class="overlay-navigation visible" role="navigation" aria-label="Elementor Menu"` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden

Comment: @j08691 No but I suspect it's a Wordpress theme and they can't change markup. Also [hidden] doesn't work in IE 11 does it?

Comment: @SpaceBeers If you read the link in my comment you'd know the IE11 answer. And I don't know what you're saying "no" to.

Answer (score 2):

In many ways. You can hide the nav by element:

```
nav { display: none; }
```

by class

```
.overlay-navigation { display: none };
```

etc.

There is a .visible class on it already which I assume is doing the opposite of this so you might have to fight that.

If you use just the 1st option you run the risk of hiding *all*  in your page so I would suggest targeting it by a parent or using the class.

Comment: thank you but the problem is im using elementor by theme OcewanWP and im download plugin Addon elementor nav and and when im open the nav this show me double menus the normal and black screen maybe you can try help me fix it? :)

Comment: @OrinDahan You need to find a unique parent of this element and use that. So something like #header nav { display: none; }.

Answer (score 1):

there is many ways

```
nav { 
display: none; 
}
```

or

```
nav {
   opacity:0
}
```

also

```
nav {
   visibility: hidden
}
```